# How to stop animation over a button from affecting the button's hover or function in general

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I keep a  button that   is  inside an animation hover intact?
If you  run  the  code  snippet below, you'd know what I  mean,  the button  is  placed  inside  the animation,   I  didn't  post the full  snippet,   just  to give you an idea,  when hovering over this animation, assuming the button is inside the center of the animation, the  button hover won't activate, or can't clicked unless the mouse  is  positioned at a certain  angle in the button.

how do I fix this bug?  I  want   to keep the button when moused over intact. and to Function properly

```css
#crosshair {
  width: 260px;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

.lBracket,
.rBracket,
.lBracket::before,
.lBracket::after,
.rBracket::before,
.rBracket::after,
.cross,
.cross:after {
  background: rgb(0,0,0);
}

.crosshairBlock,
.crosshairBlock1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.crosshairBlock {
  justify-content: center;
}

.crosshairBlock1 {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.crosshairBlock1:hover {
  animation: rotateBlock 6s infinite linear;
  cursor: crosshair;
}

.lBracket,
.rBracket {
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.lBracket::before,
.lBracket::after,
.rBracket::before,
.rBracket::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 15px;
}

.lBracket::before {
  top: 0;
}

.lBracket::after {
  bottom: 0;
}

.rBracket::before {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.rBracket::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.cross {
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 2px;
}

.cross:after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  left: -14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  width: 30px;
  animation: rotateY 4s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotateY {
  to { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
}

@keyframes rotateBlock {
  to { transform: rotateY(-360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div id="crosshair"> 
  <div class="crosshairBlock">
    <div class="cross"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="crosshairBlock1">
    <div class="lBracket"></div>
    <div class="rBracket"></div>
  </div>
</div> 
<label id="Signup"><a href="#" class="inner">register</a></label>
```

Comment: Have you tried giving the button a `z-index` greater than crosshair `<div>` elements?  Have you tried explicitly targeting the button with `CSS` selectors so that as long as the mouse is over it the hover will fire? `label > a > .inner:hover {opacity: .6;}`

Comment: Can you add the button and its styles to your example code?

Comment: @AlexanderDixon opacity worked! could you  post your  comment as answer so I   accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried giving the button a `z-index` greater than crosshair  elements? Have you tried explicitly targeting the button with CSS selectors so that as long as the mouse is over it the hover will fire? `label > a > .inner:hover {opacity: .6;}`.  The idea here is that the more granular your **CSS selector** is, the higher the chance it will take precedence over any other obscure CSS that gets inherited (although, in the end, as with most CSS issues, it comes down to trial and error, along with some educated guessing).

Comment: Opacity works at 0.9, however can we do something else to minimze  the  dimming of the style of the button? I tried higher value  of opacity but that then didn't work.

Comment: You could instead use `background-color` and use Google color picker to get the shades you're looking for.  As long as your selectors are taking effect, you're on the right path.

Comment: I mean border: and  color:, the bg of button is transparent

Comment: Type in `rgb 239 239 239` into Google search and it will give you this nice color selector snippet that allows you to get exacting colors for your hover transitions.

Comment: Got that part, I'm talking about the button original state,  the border color and  the  color the text  is written in is dimmed  on  opacity

Comment: I understand now, if you want the text to remain the same opacity you can try wrapping it in a span and forcing the `opacity: 1 !important;`.